# Sequential operation in generate statement

Tags: verilog

Is it possible to execute blocks generated by the generate statement in sequence?

Let's say generate statement generated block a, block b, block c... They all run in parallel but I have block b's inputs depend on block a's result, which dictates that they run sequentially. Is there any way to do this? I tried searching but couldn't find anything.

Here's the code snippet:

```
genvar i,j,k;
generate
for (k=1;k<6;k=k+1) begin : stepk   // number of whole operation reps
  for (i=k;i<6;i=i+1) begin : stepi // row counter
    for (j=k+1;j<6;j=j+1) begin : stepj // column counter
      //res2[i][j] = res[i][j]/ res[i][k] 
      fixed_point_div fpdiv(
                    .clk(clk),
                    .dividend_fp(res[k][i][j]),
                    .divisor_fp(res[k][i][k]),
                    .quotient_fp(res[k+1][i][j]));

      //assign res3[1][j] = res2[1][j];
      assign res[k+2][i][j] = (i==k) ? res[k+1][k][j] : (res[k+1][i][j] - res[k+1][k][j]);

    end
  end
end
endgenerate
```

Comment: "execute blocks generated" Sounds like your wanting hardware instance to be executed like software functions. To time share a single hardware block you need to create one instance and create a controller to sequence it.

Comment: Generate block is *replicating* some hardware structure according to specified pattern. If you replicate blocks which are connected to each other sequentially, the will "execute" sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine only from the code that you've provided, but if you wire several combinational modules together, each will act on the result of the previous.  Let's say you have three combinational blocks:

```
A -> B -> C
```

Since each module is combinational, it is a function only of its inputs, and so will effectively operate "sequentially" - once the outputs to A resolve, B will update, and so forth, until the results propagate to the output of module C.

However, this combinational update may take quite a long time, particularly if you have many blocks in sequence, which can lead to long cycle times.  A more efficient approach that achieves the speed benefits of parallel execution while keeping cycle times reasonable would be to **pipeline** the design by adding registers between each block:

```
A -> || -> B -> || -> C
```

This allows A, B, and C to execute simultaneously on sequential data.  You could easily modify your generate statement by registering the output of each `fixed_point_div` block before it is passed into the next one to pipeline the design.